# how to wrap the content of textview auto resize

Tags: android, android-layout, autoresize

I need to set parameters for a textview that is created dynamically, the text of the textview is from database. As some text may be large it exceeds the mobile window and continues to show the text in single line

```
    TableLayout tbl=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbla);
    TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
            TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new    TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            row.setLayoutParams(lp);
TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
            tv1.setSingleLine(false);
            tv1.setEllipsize(null);
            tv1.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
            tv1.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
            tv1.setText(log);
            row.addView(tv1);
            tbl.addView(row,i);
```

I have read some articles and made some possible properties to it.. plz help me to make it auto resize..

Comment: What do you want to happen when the text exceeds the screen width?

Comment: @joao2fast4u : It should append as a new line, but it continues to be in single line

Comment: Could you show your xml layout? It must have something to do with your `TableLayout` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this line on your code, before adding your `TextView` to the `TableRow`:

```
tv1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
```

It will make your `TextView` to always show all its height.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro.. @joao2fast4u it finally worked... I hav been asking many people, no one responded me correctly.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
TableLayout tbl=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbla);
TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
TableLayout.LayoutParams lp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
row.setLayoutParams(lp);
TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
tv1.setText(log);
row.addView(tv1,new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tbl.addView(row,i);
```